# Is there any benefit to explicitly casting one typedef type to another if they resolve to the same type?

Tags: c

In C, is it best to use explicit casts when casting from one type to another that share the same underlying value?

Consider the following code:

```
typedef int int1;
typedef int int2;

int main()
{
    int1 i = 0;
    int2 j;
    j = i; // no explicit cast
    // j = (int2) i; // explicit cast
    return 0;
}
```

Since both int1 and int2 are of underlying type int, are there any benefits to explicitly casting one type to the other?

Comment: Perhaps the question would make more sense if you said something about what kind of benefit you suppose there *might* be?  Or *why* you suppose there might be a benefit?

Comment: Because the answer is not only "no", but also that it is rarely appropriate to cast at all except for arithmetic purposes.  And also that `typedef` is way overused.  Don't `typedef` and also don't cast (except for arithmetic purposes), and you'll be just fine.

Comment: As asked the question should be answered with "No.". You might want to talk about why you are asking this, especially with a thought on the idea of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem I.e. if you explain what you want to achieve by doing something like this answers might be more to a helpful point for you. So please add some background details.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Typedefs can be useful for self-documentation purposes (e.g. in an IDE's parameter tooltips), so you might have `typedef int seconds; typedef int minutes;`. Then you would probably want to do something like `s = (seconds)(m * 60)`

Comment: IMO, @Barmar, that's abominable.  I stand by my original recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as code generation goes, the cast is unnecessary and will have no effect.

But if you're using `typedef` to define abstract types, the fact that they happen to be the same underlying type should be an implementation detail that the user shouldn't have to know; it might change over time. So ideally you should use the cast to treat them as independent types at this abstract level.

They can't be totally abstract, though. Since C doesn't have real user-defined types and operator overloading, the user needs to know whether it's an arithmetic type, so they know whether they can use arithmetic operations with it, and whether it makes sense to cast between the types.

All that said, programmers mostly don't bother with this. Since C doesn't enforce type compatibility at the `typedef` level, there's little benefit to using it for ADTs. `typedef` is primarily used for two reasons:

- Aliases for `struct XXX` and complicated types (especially function pointers)
- Names for types that are likely to change over time or between implementations (e.g. `size_t` and `pid_t`).